# Laravel 5 User Permissions: Delete a File

Tags: php, validation, laravel, filesystems

I'm programming a Filesystem in Laravel. Every user has his own ID and his own files & directories. It's already coded that every person can upload files or create folders in his ID path. But every User can delete files or directories from other User's at the moment. User A can not look into User B's Folder, but he's permitted to delete a file or folder in User B's folder.

I want a Validation that checks if the actual User have the permission to delete the file or folder, and if the user is not permitted a error message appears.

Here is some actual code I have:

```
$decodedFile = base64_decode;

    $checkArr = explode ( "/", $curDir );

    if (array_shift($checkArr) == Auth::user ()->id) {

        Storage::delete ( $decodedFile );
    }
    else {
        return Redirect::to ( '/filesystem?dir=' . $curDir )->withInput ()->withErrors ; 
    }
```

Comment: Is it a question? what's the error and message?